# div buttons are overlapping HTML

Tags: html, css, overlap

I am trying to make an online portfolio for myself and I have a bottom container for the bottom half of the screen and I would like to place 3 buttons at the top of the container.  I have got it to work except when you resize the page.  When you shrink the page's width the buttons will overlap.  How can I stop them from overlapping?  I want them to go close together side by side but not overlap.

```css
h1 {
  margin-left: 33%;
  margin-right: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#top,
#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
}

#bottom {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}

#navbuttons {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#resumebutton {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 33%;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #7dd7f5;
  text-align: center;
}

#coverletterbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 46.5%;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #7dd7f5;
  text-align: center;
}

#portfoliobutton {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 62.5%;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #7dd7f5;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>--Name Here-- Resume and Portfolio</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="height: 100%"></div>
    <div id="top"></div>


    <h1>--Name Here--</h1>

    <img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/cat-pictures/cat-pictures-20.jpg"/>

    <h1>Resume and Portfolio</h1>

    <div id="bottom">
      <div id="navbuttons">
        <div id="resumebutton">Resume</div>
        <div id="coverletterbutton">Cover Letter</div>
        <div id="portfoliobutton">Portfolio</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

I would provide an example if I knew how.

Thank you

Comment: I realize some of the tags got moved over a bit in the process of posting this

Comment: You can make an example using codepen.io or jsfiddle or any number of other tools. Also, consider dumping fixed positioning and using something that can resize properly, like flex or even floats. Finally, I don't see links in your example. Please make sure you have links, not `<div>`s with `onclick` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to absolute position the buttons if you have the container fixed. you can use `inline-block` and just `text-align: center` on your container. Also there are errors in your css, like there is no `float: center;`, you can also skip the # and use class as they share css properties. But I agree that Bootstrap is the way to go for responsive, and especially if you are new.

```
#bottom {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}

.nav-button {
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #7dd7f5;
  text-align: center;
}

<div id="bottom">
   <div class="nav-button">Resume</div>
   <div class="nav-button">Cover Letter</div>
   <div class="nav-button">Portfolio</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved my problem,  thank you so much I will be looking more into bootstrap instead of piecing it together like I have been.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is great at this. I recommend using it in combination with some of your custom styles to produce a bottom section split into equally sized columns.

Grids are split into 12 columns, so columns of 4 (e.g. col-md-4) will split into evenly spaced vertically.

For the bottom, that would look something like:

```
<div id="bottom">
      <div id="navbuttons" class="row">
        <div id="resumebutton" class="col-md-4">Resume</div>
        <div id="coverletterbutton" class="col-md-4">Cover Letter</div>
        <div id="portfoliobutton" class="col-md-4">Portfolio</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

You can make these columns wrapper divs if you want to center smaller buttons inside those columns, but the grid structure is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete attribute `position: absolute;` from all buttons ( `resumebutton`, `coverletterbutton` and `portfoliobutton`) and add `text-align: center` to `navbuttons` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the `absolute`positioning to replace the elements in question back into the flow of the document. They'll have relation to each other now, so you won't need to rely on positioning rules like `left` and `right`.
The elements are already displayed `inline-block` so just declare a `text-align: center` rule to the parent and the nested elements will align accordingly.
In the snippet example below, margins have been added around each button for spacing, repetitive rules have been replaced with one instance using a class selector applied to all button elements, note that `float: center;` is not a valid rule.

**Snippet Example**

```css
h1 {
  margin-left: 33%;
  margin-right: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#top,
#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
}
#bottom {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}
#navbuttons {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  /* invalid rule */
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbuttons .button {
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #7dd7f5;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100%"></div>
<div id="top"></div>

<h1>--Name Here--</h1>

<img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/cat-pictures/cat-pictures-20.jpg" />

<h1>Resume and Portfolio</h1>

<div id="bottom">
  <div id="navbuttons">
    <div id="resumebutton" class="button">Resume</div>
    <div id="coverletterbutton" class="button">Cover Letter</div>
    <div id="portfoliobutton" class="button">Portfolio</div>
  </div>
</div>
```